# How to delete session for specific user in cakePHP3?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

What I need to achieve is to have the possiblility for administrator to remove session of given user to force relogin. This can come in handy when for example user permissions changes. How to bind session and user together so other user can access that data?

I am using database session store so removing record from the database would result in force relogin. Also authentication is based on `Auth` component.

Here is some of my related config:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Auth',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => "/home",
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Auth',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],

            'authError' => "You have no permissions to access resource ${url}. Contact system administrator.",
            'storage' => 'Session',
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'userModel' => 'User',
                    'finder' => 'user',
                    'fields' => ['username' => 'name', 'password' => 'password']
                ]
            ],
            'authorize' => ["Controller"]
        ]);
```

And session storage:

```
   'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'database',
]
```

Below I have marked where would i place database update code. Unfortunetly after login execution, session gets "revalidated" so the ID changes. All in all, changes made in login action are not visible after redirect.

Login action:

```
public function login()
{
    $form = new LoginForm();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($form->validate($this->request->data)) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                // here would be good place to update the database 
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error("Invalid security credentials provided");
            }
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error("Invalid login form");
        }
    }
    $this->set('loginForm', $form);
}
```

Comment: The session is being renewed when the auth component writes to the session storage, so accessing the session ID after invoking `$this->Auth->setUser()` should work. What exactly have you tried?

Comment: I have tried exactly what you have mentioned. In code above i have modified database content in the place where comment is (after setUser) but this still gets overriden after redirect or new request

Comment: You need to be a little more precise, ideally show the code that you've used, and explain what exactly "_gets overriden_" means, _where_ is _what_ being overriden with _what_ data?

Comment: What i tried to bind user to session is irrelevant. The relevant part here is that on next request after login (either redirect by code or direct request from browser), new session is created (session data gets overriden in the db). I have stated in the question that `Unfortunetly after login execution, session gets "revalidated" so the ID changes` and this is my main blocker here. 
Maybe i am using Auth component wrong and this is abnormal behaviour. I dont know that ;(

Comment: It might be relevant, it might be not. Maybe what you are doing is causing the session to renew, maybe you are reading the wrong value, etc, who knows, I'm no clairvoyant, I don't know your code. You say the ID changes, but you don't explain how you tested that, so for all I know you could even be testing things in the wrong way. The session ID normally shouldn't change after `setUser()`, and in fact it doesn't do so for me, so that's all I can say at this point, I can't debug your application from here, I can only tell you about stuff that you are showing here, hence I'm asking for details.

Comment: No it is not relevant - this is what i am sure of. However you might be right that I am testing it wrong. Ill check on that tomorrow and let you know what will happen. Can you confirm that `Auth` configuration and `login` action looks more or less ok ?

Comment: You may also want to check possible 3rd party code for calls to `Session::renew()` that would cause the ID to change.

Comment: Okay, so you were right about me checking the symptoms in wrong way. So the session is in consistent state. But the session itself is flushed upon sesssion_write_close() call. So basicly, my database manipulation in the controller is useless because there is no valid data there yet, and even if they were, they would be overriden by SessionHandler. How do you propose to hook into this process? I need to update database after session is flushed into the database. I can use custom SessionHandler for this, but how to access `Auth` data from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@ndm Thanks for valuable comments and pinpoints.**

Thank to @ndm's comments I have found (most probably) viable solution. I had to inject some code into session data save process. To do that, I have used custom `SessionHandler` and PHP's `Cloasure` in role of callback.

```
class UserSession extends DatabaseSession
{
    public $callback;
    public function write($id, $data)
    {
        $result = parent::write($id, $data);
        if ($this->callback) {
            call_user_func($this->callback,$id);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

and the login action

```
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            /**  @var UserTable $model */
            $model = $this->loadModel("User");
            $handler = $this->Session->engine();
            /** @var UserSession $handler */
            $handler->callback = function ($id) use ($model, $user) {
                $model->updateSession($id, $user['id']);
            };
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
```

This way, the session row in the DB is updated AFTER session data is flushed into the DB.

Now I can query all sessions for given user, and delete them if needed forcing relogin for that user. Callback is called only once upon user login, whitch was as well my goal in matter of optimalization and avoidance of `UPDATE` query db during every http request (because that would be the solution as well, but I wanted to avoid that)

Comment: **"...and delete them if needed forcing relogin for that user..."** How? Finding session in DB using a `LIKE` operator is something I'm already using and want to avoid

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem. Either you want to query the DB or not. What operator you will use for that is up to you.

Comment: I was just trying to find if there is a better way to find user session from DB and delete (or expire) the record. My case is where I have a column in users table that controls whether login is allowed for a user or not. If I disable a (already logged in user), I want to delete his session so that he is force logged out. At present, I'm doing it by finding session data of the user using (following is SQL translated by Cake): ```SELECT `Session`.`id` FROM `my_sessions_table` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`data` LIKE '%s:2:"id";s:3:"123"%' AND `Session`.`expiry` >= **current epoch**```.

Comment: I don't have to search by string content matching but by user id because user_id is one of the columns. What you are doing is probably working, but is inefficient as no indexes are used for string part.

Comment: Sounds fairly reasonable. I'll try that by adding a column to DB schema and then in the populating user_id in `MySessionTable.php` model's `beforeSave()` (Yes, I have a model for `my_sessions_table` table where I defined couple of handy functions). Let's see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: Yay! it works. I just did ```$this->data[$this->alias]['user_id'] = CakeSession::read("Auth.User.id");``` in my `beforeSave()` of `MySessionTable` model. BTW, I'm aware that using `LIKE` as mentioned in previous comment is inefficient and that was why I wanted a better solution. Thanks again.